# Search and Replace using illegal characters Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to accomplish a search and replace in multiple files. See sample code below. But when I use the characters [] , :: , / it replaces multiple times all over the place. Is there a way around this?

```
PS C:"Some_Path"> $newFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.par -rec 
foreach ($file in $newFiles)
{(Get-Content $file.PSPath) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "[text]", " /Text/Text_Data1::[404PC001]" } | Set-Content $file.PSPath }
```

Thanks

.par is a text file

Comment: Please post sample text and what you want to find and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-replace` operator in PowerShell uses [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6). You need to quote characters that are special in these expressions. To do this in your example, add '\' before the '[' and  ']' characters as in:

```
$_ -replace "\[text\]", " /Text/Text_Data1::[404PC001]"
```

Comment: Or make PowerShell do it... `$_ -replace [regex]::escape("[text]")," /Text/Text_Data1::[404PC001]"`